# App installation failed with unknown error Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode7

My app runs in iPhone simulator smoothly, but when I tried to run on iPhone app installation failed with the following error message.

> **App installation failed**
>   An unknown error has occurred.

[image: App installation failed]

I have used valid provisioning profile in code signing, but this problem occurs randomly. When I install the same provisioning profile/create and install a new provisioning it works for sometime and again this issue happens.

Comment: What is iOS version on the device?

Comment: Maybe get a new USB cable?

Comment: add profiles in your project.

Comment: checked with iOS 8.4, 9.2 and 9.3

Answer (score 0):

Close your Xcode and Start again.

Comment: that is just a temporary solution..Any other permanent solutions...